# Как настроить функцию, процедуру и триггер, чтобы при удалении, в таблице устанавливался `NULL`?

Tags: postgresql, триггер

Имеется две таблицы, `User(int id) Message(sender_id, adresee_id)`.

В таблице сообщений два foreign key один из которых указывает на отправителя, а второй на получателя сообщения.

Как настроить функцию, процедуру и триггер, так чтобы при удалении пользователя, в таблице сообщений на место `foreign key` связанного с удаляемым пользователем устанавливалось значение `NULL`?

Answer (score 3):

Это можно задать в описании внешнего колюча. Пропишите `ON DELETE SET NULL`.
Например:

```
CONSTRAINT my_fkey FOREIGN KEY (fk_id) REFERENCES fk_table (id) ON DELETE SET NULL
```

Comment: спасибо, но можно ли это реализовать с помощью функций?

Comment: Реализовать-то можно, но смысл делать руками то, что за Вас  может сделать сама СУБД?

Comment: Я делаю бек анд на hibernate и с помощью него не смог добиться желаемого результата, когда разобрался, что cascade на уровне базы данных и объектов разные вещи, но по заданию у нас есть еще требование раелизации процедур и функций, и решил, что эту задачу можно выполнить с помощью процедур.